# PHP function param type best practices

Tags: php, frameworks

I am currently working on a framework and have come accros a snag... how should I handle incorrect parameter types when someone calls a function in the framework?

Example:

```
// Title is expected to be string, comment_num is expected to be int
function example1($title, $comment_num) {


 // Doesnt throw error, just converts type 
 $title = (string) $title;
 $comment_num = (int) $comment_num;

}
```

or

```
// Title is expected to be string, comment_num is expected to be int

function example2($title, $comment_num) {


 if (!is_string($title)) {

  trigger_error('String expected for first parameter', E_USER_WARNING);
  return;
 }

 if (!is_string($title)) {

  trigger_error('Int expected for second parameter', E_USER_WARNING);
  return
 }
}
```

Or would a mixture of both work? Throw an error and convert the type anyway?

What would be the best way of doing this? I plan on releasing it so it's not just going to be me using it, therefore I want to think of the best way for others as well. Thanks.

EDIT!!!

So I decided to give the answer but i also wanted to post the code i made which allows me to quickly check types. Its abit rough but it works well enough.

```
function __type_check($params) {

    if (count($params) < 1) {

        return; 
    }
    $types = func_get_args();
    array_shift($types);

    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    $backtrace = $backtrace[1];

    $global_types = array(
        'bool'  => 'boolean',
        'int'   => 'integer',
        'float' => 'double' 
    );

    $error = false;


    for ($i = 0, $j = count($types); $i < $j; ++$i) {

        if (strpos($types[$i], ',') === false) {

            $type = strtolower($types[$i]);

            if (isset($global_types[$type])) {

                $type = $global_types[$type];
            }

            if (gettype($params[$i]) != $type) {
                $error = true;
                break;
            }

        } else {

            $current_types = array_map('trim', explode(',', $types[$i]));

            foreach ($current_types as $type) {

                $type = strtolower($type);  

                if (isset($global_types[$type])) {

                    $type = $global_types[$type];
                }

                if (gettype($params[$i]) == $type) {

                    continue 2; 
                }
            }

            $error = true;
            break;
        }       
    }

    if ($error) {
        trigger_error($backtrace['function'] . '() expects parameter ' . ($i + 1) . ' to be ' . $types[$i] . ', ' . gettype($params[$i]) . ' given', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
function string_manipulation($str, $str2, $offset = 1) {

    if (!__type_check(func_get_args(), 'string', 'string', 'int,float')) {

        return false;   
    }   

    // do manipulation here
}
```

That would basically check that the first and second parameters are strings, and the 3rd parameter is an integer or a float. You can combine any types 'string,int,array,object' etc and all valid types are taken from gettype

/* Known bugs */
null is a type, cant decide on if it should be or not
if you enter a class name, it doesn't check instance of but just does typecheck
havent figured out a good way to trigger the error... meh

Thats it from me, the bugs can be easily fixed :D

Comment: My suggestion: Don't use `trigger_error`.  Throw exceptions.  They are much more flexible and easier to deal with effectively.

Comment: an exception for something as trivial as a data type seems abit much though.. you cant really expect people to run every function within a try/catch

Comment: Not answering your question here, but if you're building a framework, you might be better off creating a single function that does the checks for you, and your other functions/classes refer to that single function.

Comment: What Ozzy said. Since PHP uses `E_WARNING` for its built-in functions, most coders expect `E_WARNING` or `E_USER_WARNING` errors to arise from incorrectly-typed arguments. `trigger_error()` is OK here IMO.

Comment: Look at what the existing libraries do. Many of them return errors, but some *also* throw warnings, which is Very Annoying (`fopen()` is my favourite example). I would say if you can convert a paremeter with no loss of information, do so, if not, return an error code.

Comment: @static I find warnings to be **extremely helpful** for debugging. Could you elaborate why you find them annoying?

Comment: Considering that I always install an ErrorException error handler, I don't use the standard error reporting system at all.  I can't stand it (since it's a pita to detect and capture errors, so you need to add other checks like return values).  At least with an Exception it requires you to at least acknowledge errors.  Warnings and Notices can be trivially ignored.  And as far as it appearing a bit much, there's a reason there's a `InvalidArgumentException` defined in SPL.  Different ways of approaching the problem, but I personally consider `trigger_error` to be bad practice....

Comment: @irc `trigger_error` *alone* is of course no error reporting mechanism. It's just to aid debugging, which it does very well. The real error is reported with a bad return value you need to check for in your code. As such, this approach differs from exceptions only in its severity and scope. Using exceptions for *all* error reporting is *abusing* them, I agree with Ozzy there. Some functions are better off returning `false` and optionally triggering an error/warning, while others should throw exceptions. Many people have fought holy wars over this difference already though. :)

Comment: I am the lead developer on my company's PHP framework system. When we started the entire system used `trigger_error`. We found that switching to using Exceptions and **building our own logging system** was far more powerful, easier to write, debug, and test.

Comment: @deceze This specific problem is isolated to a very small number of functions, of which `fopen()` is the most visible culprit. It *already* returns `false` if it can't open the file, which is easily checked for. So why does it have to thrown an error *as well* - and that's my beef. Sure, it makes sense if there should be no reason for the failure, but I often have circumstances where I can only tell there is failure because `fopen()` can't open the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.

PHP is a dynamically typed language, and sometimes for a good reason. Since it deals a lot with HTTP data, which is all strings all the time, numbers aren't necessarily always of type `int` and will still work fine for general operations.

Strictly enforcing primitive types is often very un-PHPish and could be a hassle to work with.

The usual way to do things in PHP is to accept arguments in almost any type and work with them in good faith until you need to have specific results or the type becomes an issue.

```
function example1($title, $comment_num) {

    // do some operations that should work error-free regardless of type

    if ($result != 'something specific you expect here') {
        throw new Exception('Something went wrong!');
        // or
        trigger_error('Something went wrong!');
        return false;
    }

    // continue with $result
}
```

You can go the OOP route and construct objects this way. Objects will be flexible to some degree in what they accept. If they succeed in being constructed, you have a defined object of a specific type that you can use for PHP-enforced type hinting:

```
function example1(TitleObject $title) {
    // rest assured that $title is of the right type
}
```

Comment: This is how I would approach it as well. +1 for the OOP route!

Answer (score 0):

If anything, just use SPLTypes and be done; otherwise throw InvalidArgument exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I would typecast the int and string datatypes automatically with no complaint (because they could be easy to mix up), but for something like a resource or object it could be a useful feature to notify the programmer of an error.

I would also set up the notification code in its own function so things wouldn't get so repetitive. Anyways, Good luck!