# Variable type validation

Tags: php, typechecking

I have methods which parameters can only handle certain types of variable. I have a few ideas on how to validate these type and I need your help to choose the best way.
I could:

- Just return `false` if one of the types of variable is wrong, without letting the user know what's happening. Plus, if the function's output isn't usually checked by the user--e.g. `ob_start()`--they won't know it's even wrong;
- Throw a custom [`InvalidArgumentException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) saying "Type of parameter X is incorrect." Thus I have to check every single parameter, making the code unreadable. Plus, the exception actually has to be catched, and I dislike these `try...catch` in my code.
- Call `error_log()`. But yet I have to check every single parameter.

What option would you choose? Why? Otherwise, do you have a better idea?

---

**UPDATE**
When I talk about types, I mean these:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function param type best practises](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754759/php-function-param-type-best-practises)

Comment: Prefer `assert(is_bool($arg1));` for such cases. Invalid parameter types are foremost a development stage problem, not a runtime issue. Only if you have a highly polymorphic type system InvalidArgExcpt becomes a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do type checking in php is using the built-in function. You can find a list here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php It's a real pain in the ass, but you have no choice.

For the checking itself, I'll check all the parameters type at the beginning of the function and throw an error if not. Then you can always add some debuging print_r to discover the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking to arguments passed in your code of course you MUST log errors and fix every possibile mistakes in your code.

Example:

```
function(){
    if (!is_array($arg))
       trigger_error();
}
```

## OR

Using only objects you can specify the type of arguments

Example:

```
function yay(Class1 $arg1, Class2 $arg2){
    //That's it!
}
```

Comment: how does this check the type of the variable ?

Comment: Dunno if the OP meant the users POSTed or GETed, in the othercase anyway I suggested the best way is to error_log possibile errors

Comment: You misunderstood. See original post update. Thank you for taking time, but you'd better rewrite your answer or rather delete it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Using only objects you can specify the type of arguments?"

Comment: Edited the answer with example

Comment: By doing so I can force the parameter to be an instance of a specific class or an array. That is all. What if I want it to be a string, an integer?