# PHP - way to validate many parameters of a function call quickly

Tags: php

I have identified an issue that always produce bugs in my application. It is that PHP is generally quite lax about passing null or empty variables to a function. For example

```
function do_this($a, $b, $c) {
....
}
```

One error-prone call could be

```
do_this($request['a'], $request['b'], $request['c']);
```

As PHP just silently passes null if any of the keys is not found. I have tried use doing error checking inside the function, as below:

```
function do_this($a, $b, $c) {
    if (empty($a)) throw new Exception('$a is not defined!');
    if (empty($b)) throw new Exception('$b is not defined!');
    if (empty($c)) throw new Exception('$c is not defined!');
}
```

It's a headache when the function takes many parameters.

I could use E_STRICT, but I am using many third-party plugins and working off Wordpress, so I'll be getting warnings from other packages.

What's a good way to validate many parameters of a function call in PHP?

Comment: Just saying: `empty()` will catch 0, "0", "", false and null.

Comment: `assert(!empty($a) && !empty($b))` is more concise. Btw `NULL` is a perfectly valid value. PHP can only generate a hint at your array accesses if `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL`.

Answer (score 1):

First off. you shouldn't be passing values without checking your indices like that. That's very very bad.

As for your question, why not just define default values and then loop through your variables to print an error?

```
function do_this($a = null, $b = null, $c = null) {
   $numargs = func_num_args();
   $arg_list = func_get_args();
   for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
       if ($arg_list[$i] == null) {
           //fail
       }
   }
}
```

You don't need all that code of course, just an example.

See here for more info : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to use `empty` inside your function, since the variables are certainly `set`. `if (!$a)` will do.
- It's always possible to pass incorrect **values**, regardless of whether this happens due to variables not being set in the scope calling the function or just because the values are bad. At some point you need to check anyway. See [PHP function param type best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754759/php-function-param-type-best-practises).
- You must check in the scope *calling* the function for non-existing variables, not within the function. I.e.:

  ```
  if (isset($foo, $bar, $baz)) {
      do_this($foo, $bar, $baz);
  }
  ```

  You must always do this if there's a legitimate chance the variables may not exist, this is not specific to passing them as parameters to functions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [args module](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#nsplargs) from [NSPL](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl). It makes argument validation an easy process. To check all arguments in the function from your example you just have to add only one line of code:

```
function do_this($a, $b, $c) 
{
    expectsAll([nonEmpty, int], [$a, $b, $c]);
    // do this...
}
```

More examples [here](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl/blob/master/examples/args.php).